# In Objective-C, can protocols be "instantiated" using derived classes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have written a protocol in Objective-C, named `BHIDataFormatter`, which is implemented by  `BHCsvDataFormatter`, `BHJsonFormatter`, and `BHXmlFormatter` classes.

As a .NET developer primarily, the required instance can be obtained via:

```
IDataFormatter formatter;
if (csv) formatter = new CsvDataFormatter();
else if (json) formatter = new JsonFormatter();
else if (xml) formatter = new XmlDataFormatter();
else throw SomeException("Cripes");
```

Basically, how can I do the same in Objecive-C? I have tried, although `BHIDataFormatter` is an "unknown type":

```
BHIDataFormatter* formatter;
if (csv) formatter = [[BHCsvDataFormatter alloc] init];
else if (json) formatter = [[BHJsonDataFormatter alloc] init];
else if (xml) formatter = [[BHXmlDataFormatter alloc] init];
else [[NSException exceptionWithName:@"SomeException" reason:@"Cripes" userInfo:nil] raise];
```

The following seems to work, although it seems too generic (I would rather specifically use `BHIDataFormatter` explicitly):

```
Protocol* formatter = [[CsvDataFormatter alloc] init];
```

Comment: The `BHIDataFormatter* formatter;` declaration would only work if `BHIDataFormatter` were the superclass of the other three rather than a protocol that they implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the variable as type `id` that conforms to the protocol

```
id<BHIDataFormatter> formatter;
```

That is `id` is a pointer to any object and
you are also claiming that the object will conform to `BHIDataFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

As Paul already stated, you need to use

```
id<MyProtocolName> myNewVariable;
```

Here is a good intro:

http://mauvilasoftware.com/iphone_software_development/2008/05/a-brief-intro-to-objective-c-p.html